# Ruby WHERE Clause - Listing Duplicate Objects(Postgresql)

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, postgresql

I am working on determining the attitude of a post using AFINN 111, which can be found 
[here](http://code.google.com/p/fb-moody/source/browse/trunk/AFINN/AFINN-111.txt?r=2). Whenever one of these words are mentioned in the post, their corresponding values are selected and added, to give the cumulative score, which helps in determining the nature of the post, whether +ve or -ve.

I have an array `content = ["bad", "bad", "dog"]`.
I want to get the total score for the words being used in this post. so, i fire a db query.

```
score = Sentiment.where(word: content).pluck(:value).inject(:+)
```

The result i get is -3. The word "bad" has a corresponding score of -3. since the word "bad" repeats two times, i want the resultant score to be -6.

I tried firing this in rails console to check how many objects are being returned.

```
 Sentiment.where(:id => [1,1])
```

returns only one object...Is there any option that will allow the duplicate values to be returned?

One fairly simple solution is to iterate through the array.

```
score = 0
content.each do |word|
score += Sentiment.where(word: word).pluck(:value).first
end
```

but this will involve firing n number of queries, rather than finishing the job with a single query... Is there any other way of achieving this?

Comment: You could store the count of each word in the database if you have the ability to process the content before insertion. You probably need to change the data type of the column to a hstore.

Alternatively you may be able to do a count on the word returning an integer that you can multiply by your score.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another solution with one query:

```
content = ['bad', 'bad', 'dog']

sentiments = Sentiment.where(word: content).group_by(&:word)

score = 0

content.each do |word|
  score += sentiments[word].score if sentiments[word]
end

score #=> -6
```

Comment: Thankyou.. I made a small modification to ur code...

i added this condition..

  **if sentiments[word].present?**

 
This way, we can avoid nil class error for those words that are not there in the sentiment model :) i will vote ur answer up once i get the minimum rep points.. :)

Comment: Oh, yes you're right for the condition. Thanks for the points!